# Converting a character into keycode

Tags: android

I have a character and I want to convert it into KeyEvent KeyCode constraints http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_0

Like if I have a character '0' I wan to convert into

> Key code constant: '0' key.
>
> Constant Value: **7** (0x00000007)

as specified in the KeyEvent page. What can be a best method for doing this? Is there any predefined function to do it?

Comment: Will you know the character that needs to be converted? Is it a constant or will it change depending on the user?

Comment: Different keyboards will use different constants... that being said, KEYCODE_0 is a `public static final int` so you can invoke that name instead of any number 7 thruout your app... Personally, my lucky numbers are KEYCODE_0 and KEYCODE_6.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was going to mention but it's not quite as easy if it's not a constant.

Comment: what characters do you need to convert exactly (only alpha num, or more ?) ?

Answer (score 14):

Here is a solution I use to put chars in a webview:

```
char[] szRes = szStringText.toCharArray(); // Convert String to Char array

KeyCharacterMap CharMap;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) // My soft runs until API 5
    CharMap = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD);
else
    CharMap = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.ALPHA);

KeyEvent[] events = CharMap.getEvents(szRes);

for(int i=0; i<events.length; i++)
    MainWebView.dispatchKeyEvent(events[i]); // MainWebView is webview
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm still new to Java/Android, so my answer may not work out of the box, but you may still get the idea.

```
import android.view.KeyCharacterMap;
import android.view.KeyEvent;    
...
public class Sample {
    ...
    public boolean convertStringToKeyCode(String text) {

        KeyCharacterMap mKeyCharacterMap = 
            KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD);

        KeyEvent[] events = mKeyCharacterMap.getEvents(text.toCharArray());

        for (KeyEvent event2 : events) {
            // We get key events for both UP and DOWN actions,
            // so we may just need one.
            if (event2.getAction() == 0) {
                int keycode = event2.getKeyCode();
                // Do some work
            }
        }
}
```

I got the idea when I was reading the code of `sendText` method in `uiautomator` framework [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-4.1.2_r2.1/uiautomator/library/src/com/android/uiautomator/core/InteractionController.java):

Comment: This is nice! the reference to uiautomator source code provides good assurance.

Answer (score 4):

Very rude solution but works for most characters.

Remember to do an uppercase if your text contains lowercase letters, you can add META_SHIFT_ON in that case if you then send a `KeyEvent`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        final char ch = text.charAt(i);
        try {
            dispatch(KeyEvent.class.getField("KEYCODE_" + ch).getInt(null));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(_TAG, "Unknown keycode for " + ch);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot read a character "0" from the input and use a magical function to transform that to KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 ... If you do, you will have to write a parser that switches on the read letter and return these values yourself.

For all I know, before reading the character you should've captured the thing in the `onKey()`. Depending on the number of keys you need to handle this way, a virtual android keyboard might be your only option, if this boilerplate code doesn't do the trick

```
switch(keyPress)
{
  case '0': return KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0;
  case '1': return ...
  //...
  case 'Z': return KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z;
}
```