# How to get small hand characters in android to dispatch a keyEvent?

Tags: java, android

KeyCode from `KeyEvent.class` do not contain small hand characters. How can I get KeyEvent for a letter that do not exist on that class? For example, I can get a field for following:

```
Field f = KeyEvent.class.getField("KEYCODE_" + 'A'); // also available 1-9, A-Z.
```

But I can not get for following:

```
Field f = KeyEvent.class.getField("KEYCODE_" + 'a');
```

Or what should I use to dispatch a keyEvent on android?

dispatch related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18660207/7291498).

Comment: The difference between `A` and `a` is not the primary keycode, but rather the state of meta keys (in this case, the Shift key). `KEYCODE_A` refers to the key on the keyboard that emits an `a` on its own and emits an `A` when combined with the Shift key. The `A` in `KEYCODE_A` is not a statement of the capitalization of the associated key -- it is simply the C-style CAPITAL_SNAKE_CASE convention used for many constants in the Android SDK.

Comment: I need to send command for `a` but I do not understand what code to exactly send to dispatch this or such event. I can also dispatch shift key with int 59 but what will give me `a`? If I convert `a` to `A` then send it with shift key on, then may this happen but I dont know how to send both key events at the same time or dispatch something else.